# JavaScript setTimeout, using call to change this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two simple links that when clicked should wait one second and then add a class that changes the color of the text.  The working version uses `$.proxy` and the non-working version I'm trying to use native JavaScript to change the meaning of `this`.  Why is `btnWaitNoProxy` this still referring to the global object?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z2MJ/)

code:

```
var obj = {
            wait: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log('inside the setTimeout');
                    $(this).addClass('lesson');
                    //refers to global object in the console
                }, 1000);
            }
        };

$('#btnProxy').on('click', function () {
            console.log('preparing to add class...');
            setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                $(this).addClass('lesson')
                console.log(this);
            }, this), 1000);
        });
        $('#btnWaitNoProxy').on('click', function () {
            console.log(this);
            //call still refers to the global object
            obj.wait.call(this);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `setTimeout` in `wait`, so that callback method passed to `setTimeout` will be executed in the global context by default.

One possible solution is to use $.proxy() as you have done again with the `setTimeout` handler

```
var obj = {
    wait: function () {
        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            console.log('inside the setTimeout');
            $(this).addClass('lesson');
            //refers to global object in the console
        }, this), 1000);
    }
};
```

Another is to use a closure variable like

```
var obj = {
    wait: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('inside the setTimeout');
            $(self).addClass('lesson');
            //refers to global object in the console
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: I think a light bulb just clicked for me on exactly WHY to use `self = this` or `that=this`! :)

Answer (score 0):

> When you pass a method to `setTimeout()` (or any other function, for that matter), it will be invoked with a wrong `this` value.
>
> Code executed by `setTimeout()` is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the `this` keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or `global`) object; it will not be the same as the `this` value for the function that called `setTimeout`.
>
> **Source:** [MDN — window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

There are plenty solutions:

1. Using `$.proxy`
2. Using `Function.prototype.bind`
3. Aliasing `this`